# How can I create package-scoped templates?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm making a large Meteor app and all my templates are now named `"veryLongNameOfMyTemplate"`.
I want to avoid having such long names.
I tried to create my templates in packages but I have a strange issue: while most package variables are file-scoped or package-scoped, templates are not: they are global by default.

How can I create package-scoped templates?

Comment: i'm trying to understand the question. What is wrong with just using your own namespace, e.g. `Template._myns_template1`? Whatever you do won't be truly private anyways, since packages are distributed as source files. Could you clarify what you mean by private?

Comment: I don't need to create private template, I want to create package-scoped templates. Read my question, please ;)

Comment: Looking at https://trello.com/c/igqeUcwM/17-template-and-helper-namespacing it seems to be a requested feature, but not currently possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Looking at trello.com/c/igqeUcwM/17-template-and-helper-namespacing it
>   seems to be a requested feature, but not currently possible.

Thanks, @christian-fritz